# Jetpack Compose UI not updating when stateflow changes

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

So, I have a chat app with a counter for how many messages user can send (that part is happening on backend when user is created). I'm using mutableStateFlow with initial value of null. It gets updated depending on user status - if user status' response is successful and data is not null it updates the values of messagesLeft and it decrements when user sends a message (i'm just getting that decremented value again from backend). What happens now is that I open the app and it's showing that counter is null, i send a message and it shows 10 (it's supposed to show 9). I send message again and it shows the new values (but it gets down to 1 instead of 0 because of that initial first message).

Here's part of my code:

```
  private val _messagesLeftCount: MutableStateFlow<Int?> = MutableStateFlow(null)
        val messagesLeftCount: StateFlow<Int?> = _messagesLeftCount.asStateFlow()

init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _userStatus.collectLatest {
                if (it is CommonResponse.Success && it.data != null) {
                    _messagesLeftCount.emit(it.data.messageLeft)
                }
            }
        }

@Composable
fun MainScreen(mainViewModel: MainViewModel) {

    val messagesLeftCount by mainViewModel.messagesLeftCount.collectAsState()


    MyTheme {
        Surface(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background,
        ) {
            Box(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                Column(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                    Row(
                        Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background),
                        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                    ) {
              
                        Text(
                            if (messagesLeftCount != null)
                                "Messages left: $messagesLeftCount"
                            else "",
                            color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary,
                            fontSize = 14.sp,
                            modifier = padding
                        )
                    }
                    TextInput(
                        mainViewModel = mainViewModel
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you try updating ```_messagesLeftCount``` as doing : ```_messagesLeftCount.update { it }``` instead of ```_messagesLeftCount.emit(it.data.messageLeft)```?. I assume that you are losing some state because of your updation method.

Comment: Have you tried logging or debugging the values received from the backend?

Comment: I typically use `collect` instead of `collectLatest` - does this help?

Comment: What also could help is replacing `_messagesLeftCount.emit(x)` with `_messagesLeftCount.value = x`

Answer (score -1):

you can try LaunchedEffect for better result. so you can update your messageLeft in UI inside the LaunchedEffect and It seems like it would be better if you gave an initial value other than null, but I'm not sure.

something like this:

```
LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    mainViewModel.userStatus.collectLatest { userStatus ->
        if (userStatus is CommonResponse.Success && userStatus.data != null) {
            _messagesLeftCount.value = userStatus.data.messageLeft
        }
    }
}
```